# Simpler URL helpers for custom nested routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following routes for [my application](https://travis-lite.com/):

```
TravisLite::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :repositories, path: ':owner_name', only: %i[index show], param: :name, constraints: OwnerNameContraint do
    resources :builds, only: %i[index show]
    resources :jobs, only: %i[show]
  end
end
```

This allows me to have URLs such as `/travis-ci/travis-ci/builds/12345`. The routes themselves work great, but I'm having some trouble generating the paths and URLs to the pages.

Right now, in order to link to a build, I have to do this:

```
repositories_build_path(owner_name: repository.owner_name, repository_name: repository.name, id: build.id)
```

What I would like to do is something more like this:

```
repositories_build_path([repository, build])
```

Is there a way to do this, or at least simplify the URL helper calls, without changing my URL scheme? I'm happy to change the routes themselves, as long as URLs remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this is how I do it currently, and may also be the best way to do it:

I have [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) installed, so my `BuildDecorator` looks something like this:

```
class BuildDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def path
    h.repository_build_path(
      owner_name: object.repository.owner_name,
      repository_nane: object.repository.name,
      id: object.id,
    )
  end
end
```

I have similar methods for other paths. This allows me to do the following in views:

```
link_to build.number, build.path
```